# Cached property vs Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, lazy-loading

In .NET 4 the following snippet with a cached property can also be written using the [`System.Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28VS.100%29.aspx) class. I measured the performance of both approaches and it's pretty much the same. Is there any real benefit or magic for why I should use one over the other?

**Cached Property**

```
public static class Brushes
{
    private static LinearGradientBrush _myBrush;

    public static LinearGradientBrush MyBrush
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myBrush == null)
            {
                var linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush { ...};
                linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( ... );
                linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( ... );

                _myBrush = linearGradientBrush;
            }

            return _myBrush;
        }
    }
}
```

**Lazy<T>**

```
public static class Brushes
{
    private static readonly Lazy<LinearGradientBrush> _myBrush =
        new Lazy<LinearGradientBrush>(() =>
            {
                var linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush { ...};
                linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( ... );
                linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( ... );

                return linearGradientBrush;
            }
        );

    public static LinearGradientBrush MyBrush
    {
        get { return _myBrush.Value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: By using `Lazy<T>` you're being `Lazy` to write your own implementation. (In a good way, of course.)

Comment: Interesting, I was inclined to say it's less code and more readable, but your example demonstrates this isn't quite the case. But then again, I already have a `Property<T>` class for backing fields that supports this and more common backing field behavior.

Comment: Lazy<T> allows thread safety

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I would use `Lazy<T>` in general:

- It's thread-safe (may not be an issue in this case, but would be in others)
- It makes it obvious what's going on just by the name
- It allows null to be a valid value

Note that you don't *have* to use a lambda expression for the delegate. For example, here's an approach which may be slightly cleaner:

```
public static class Brushes
{
    private static readonly Lazy<LinearGradientBrush> _myBrush =
        new Lazy<LinearGradientBrush>(CreateMyBrush);

    private static LinearGradientBrush CreateMyBrush()
    {
        var linearGradientBrush = new LinearGradientBrush { ...};
        linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( ... );
        linearGradientBrush.GradientStops.Add( ... );

        return linearGradientBrush;
    }

    public static LinearGradientBrush MyBrush
    {
        get { return _myBrush.Value; }
    }
}
```

This is particularly handy when the creation process gets complicated with loops etc. Note that by the looks of it, you could use a collection initializer for `GradientStops` in your creation code.

Another option is *not* to do this lazily, of course... unless you have several such properties in your class and you only want to create the relevant objects on a one-by-one basis, you could rely on lazy class initialization for many situations.

As noted in DoubleDown's answer, there's no way of resetting this to force recomputation (unless you make the `Lazy<T>` field not readonly) - but I've very rarely found that to be important.

Comment: In what case would be using Lazy an issue ?

Comment: @user256034: When you're not using .NET 4 :)

Comment: Thanks! The 3 points in your list are exactly what I was searching for ;)

Comment: Good list of points, if you agree with the answer of @DoubleDown and would consider adding their point to your answer, I will upvote :)

Comment: @tsemer: It's not something I've personally found useful, but I've added a small note.

Comment: Fair enough, but as it is *a* difference I wanted it to appear in the answer I'm upvoting. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 7):

Use `Lazy<T>`, as it expresses exactly what you are doing - lazy loading.

In addition, it keeps your property very clean and is thread safe.

Answer (score 4):

Typically the only reason to not use lazy is to reset the variable to null so the next access causes it to load again.  Lazy has no reset and you'd need to recreate the lazy from scratch.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961252/reset-system-lazy/6255398#6255398

Comment: Good point! IMHO, this in combination with @JonSkeet's answer is the full answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Lazy<T>` will correctly handel concurrent scenarios (if you pass in the correct [LazyThreadSafetyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx) ) while your example does not have any thread-safety checks.

Answer (score 1):

The `Lazy<T>` is simpler—it clearly expresses the intent of the code.
It's also thread safe.

Note that if you're actually using this on multiple threads, you need to make it `[ThreadStatic]`; GDI+ objects cannot be shared across threads.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy has some syncronization overhead to provide thread-safety whereas cached property is initiliazed  by CLR way before any other code and you do not need to pay synronization cost

From a testability point of view, Lazy is well tested and proven artifact.

However, it has a very slight overhead, in my opinion, over other option

Comment: Lazy supports a ['None' thread-safety mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529533/system-lazyt-with-different-thread-safety-mode).

Answer (score -1):

Well if your performance is about the same then the only reason to use `Lazy<T>` over the cached version would be if you aren't sure if the user is actually going to load the property.

The point of `Lazy<T>` is to wait until the user needs the resource and then create it at that instance in time. If they are always going to need to resource then there is no point in using `Lazy<T>`, unless you need some of it's other purposes such as it being thread safe.

Comment: -1, OP's alternative is identical in the sense that if the property is never called then the list is never instantiated. In that sense they are both "lazy".