# Lazy Initialization always returns null

Tags: c#, singleton, lazy-loading

I have the following class that suppose to create iterate through a string array to check if a code exists. However the .value always returns null when using Lazy Initialization.

```
public class LazyInclusionList
{
    private string docCopyCode;
    private Lazy<LazyInclusionList> _docCopyCodeList = null;
    public LazyInclusionList()
    { }

    public bool GetDocCodes(string docCopyNumber)
    {
        docCopyCode = new string(docCopyNumber.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
        _docCopyCodeList = new Lazy<LazyInclusionList>();
        bool docCopyCheck = false;
        int last = _docCopyCodeList.Value.GetDocCodesDB.Count();
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string code in _docCopyCodeList.Value.GetDocCodesDB)
        {
            if(docCopyCode == code)
            {
                docCopyCheck = true;
            }
            else if (docCopyCode != code && ++i == last)
            {
                docCopyCheck = false;
            }
        }
        return docCopyCheck;
    }

    private string[] codes;
    public string[] GetDocCodesDB
    {
        set
        {
            codes = value;
        }
        get { return codes; }
    }
```

}

I have the following test method that I use to check this code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckURLList()
    {
        var list = new LazyInclusionList();
        string[] array = new string [3] { "CB", "DB", "T" };
        list.GetDocCodesDB = array;
        string myTest = "CB10/00/1";
        Assert.IsTrue(list.GetDocCodes(myTest));
    }
```

This is the first time I use this method and dont understand it fully.

Comment: I don't see constructor or field/property initializer are doing anything, so how do you expect  `GetDocCodes()` method is executed (not talking about your test, but about something what will use that type)? You are misunderstanding [`Lasy<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx) pattern. Maybe if you explain in words what are you trying to achieve then it would be easier to answer.

Comment: The string array will be stored in the DB and do not want to make the trip every time it is needed, if it is at all (GetDocCodesDB). I am expecting for GetDocCodes to do the work(return true/false), and the lazy pattern to manage the call to  GetDocCodesDB. I hope that clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to recognize known patterns in your example and I decide to explain the idea in simple words.

> The string array will be stored in the DB and do not want to make the trip every time it is needed

That's basically this

```
string[] _codes;
public string[] Codes
{
    get
    {
        if (_codes == null) // check if not initialized yet
        {
            _codes = ... // fill from database
        }
        return codes;
    }
}
```

As soon as you read `Codes` value for the first time its obtained and result is *cached*. `null` is used as *special value* to run initialization once (another `bool` field can be used if `null` is expected as result of `_codes`).

---

`Lazy<>` is doing the same (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5134786/1997232) for insights) and its used like this:

```
readonly Lazy<string[]> _codes = new Lazy<string[]>(() =>
{
    return ... // return here string[] which you fill from database
});
public string[] Codes => _codes.Value; // property used to get value
```

Note: initialization of `Lazy<>` (that lambda used to calculate its `Value`) will only run once, same as with caching example above. For initialization to occurs you only have to access `Codes` property once, any further call will return *cached* result.

Comment: I am still somehow faced with the same issue where `_codes` is null even though I have given `string[] codes` values

Comment: Then `null` is a result of what you read from database (the code what returns `string[]` returns `null`). Either set a breakpoint to see it or make some debug output. My concerns (and answer) were mostly of how you implement `Lazy<>`.